# Adjust topic title length on topic listing page (Advanced Forum)

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I'm trying to find the right  way of adjusting the topic title length displayed on the topic listing page generated by Advanced Forum (mysite.com/forum/[myforum]).

I tried to manipulate the title variable offered by the `template-advanced-forum.naked.topic-list-view.tpl.php` and the corresponding theme function but it gives me formatted HTML like this:

```
<a href="/debatindlaeg/lorem-ipsum-lorem-ipsum-lorem-ipsum-lorem-ipsum-lorem-ipsum-lorem-ipsum-lorem-ipsum" title=" lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum   "><span class="forum-topic-title">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </span> </a> <br /> by <span class="username" xml:lang="" typeof="sioc:UserAccount" property="foaf:name">Anonym</span> » ons, 18/01/2012 - 17:05
```

My guess is that I need to go "further back" in the theming process somehow to get a hold of the title variable, but I must admit this is beyond my Drupal skills. Any suggestions?

I am using D7 and [Advanced Forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) (version 7.x-2.0-beta1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but Advanced Forum integrates itself with Views.

So (assuming you have the Views module), you can trim the length of the title field in the `advanced_forum_topic_list` view. This c done by clicking the `Content: Title (Topic / Topic starter)` field, going to *'Rewrite results'* and checking *'Trim this field to a maximum length'*.

Because the field contains HTML to insert a span tag, you'll have to add 32 to the trim count (e.g. if you want to trim to 20 chars, enter 52), and ensure *'Field can contain HTML'* is checked.

Comment: Yes yes yes exactly what I was looking for - hadn't noticed the Views integration, that makes perfect sense, once you see it. Thanks!